# Output data file using "put"

Tags: sas

I'm new to SAS and using `put` in the output of a delimited data file but a couple of questions.

1. In the output a space is generated between the delimiter and the data. Can this space be eliminated?
2. In my code how do I incorporate `replace`? I tried and the code error'd out.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

```
data _null_; 
set datain_20130108;
file 'C:\data\dataout_20130108.dlm';
put "!" id "|" var1 "|" var2 "|" var3 "|" var4 "|" var5 "|" var6 "~";
run;
```

Comment: As Aaron says, the second part of your question isn't clear.  What do you mean by "replace"?  If you tried something, post the code any any error messages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding the space, use +(-1) after the variable name as shown below.

```
put "!" id+(-1);
```

Regarding the replace, I do not understand your question. See the link to replace documentation below.
http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000131176.htm

Comment: thanks for the above code. As for the "replace" it appears I don't need to use that in a data step.

Answer (score 2):

Why not just put out a delimited file the normal way?  You'll have to do some goofy things to get the leading/trailing characters (which I'd be very curious why they exist) but it's probably simpler than manually delimiting the file.

```
data _null_; 
set datain_20130108;
file 'C:\data\dataout_20130108.dlm' dlm='|';
idtemp= cats("!", id);
vartemp=cats(var6,'~');
put  id $ var1 var2 var3 var4 var5 var6 $;
run;
```

REPLACE is likely coming from some instruction to use PROC EXPORT.  If you don't have REPLACE on PROC EXPORT, it won't overwrite a file.  SAS data steps will replace files without requiring the option.

```
proc export data=datain_20130108 file='C:\data\dataout_20130108.dlm' dbms=dlm replace;
delimiter='|';
run;
```

However that would not give you the extra characters on the beginning and end, and I highly recommend not using PROC EXPORT for delimited files unless it's just a one-off shot - it makes all sorts of decisions for you that you're better off making yourself (formatting, etc.) and really isn't much easier than the PUT version.

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to use REPLACE in your PUT statement, if that is what you meant. You will need to create a new variable (using whatever functions you need) then use that variable in your PUT statement.